# Define a generic type with specified key passed to a function

Tags: typescript-generics

Is there a way to convert the following JS snippet to TS?

```
function generate(key) {
  return {
    [key]: 'success',
  };
}

const obj = generate('result');
```

`typeof obj` should be `{ result: string }`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use a generic to "store" the type of `key` and then use it in the return type (which is a mapped type).

```
function generate<Key extends string>(key: Key): { [P in Key]: string } {
```

Comment: The return statement yields the following error:
`Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ [P in Key]: string; }'`

Comment: This is the working example:
```function generate<Key extends string>(key: Key): { [P in Key]: string } {
  return {
    [key]: 'success',
  } as { [P in Key]: string };
}
```


The tricky part is `Key extends string`, never used a generic for a key in this way. Thank you!